# Data won't console.log in async (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the [library API](http://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien) here to basically fetch the title of books.

Before I move on, I need to atleast check and see if I am properly pulling out the data. So on my code:

```
  async fetchRandomBooks() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien',
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({books: json, isFetching: false});
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({errorMessage: error});
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRandomBooks();
    console.log(this.state.books);
  }
```

I tried console.log inside the `fetchRandomBooks` as well as inside the `componentDidMount` but it did not gave me any data. As far as I remember you need to pick up on `response.docs` in order to pull something from the api.

Any idea how can I properly console.log the data and probably return something from it? I just want to make sure I am pulling out the data before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access `console.log(this.state.books);` in `componentDidMount()` because the API call is ongoing and it's taking a bit of time for complaining about it.

You can also try with react hooks.

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = React.useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchRandomBooks = async () => {
    setFetching(true);
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        "http://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien"
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json.docs);
      setData(json.docs);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setFetching(false);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchRandomBooks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {fetching && <p>Loading...</p>}
      <ul>
        {data?.map((item) => {
          return <li>{item.title}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The api call is not even pulling out the data and assigning it to the state.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). It gets invoked **immediately** after an update to the component, may that be new props or an update to state.

Your code could look something like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  console.log(this.state.books)
}
```

Comment: The api call is not even pulling out the data and assigning it to the state.